# Ion-Button color="x" rendered as white

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app that uses both Ionic Themes and Angular Materials.  In some instances I am using  and in some of those instances I am attempting to change the button color as such    for example.  When setting the ion-button to any given color it is rendered as white.

I've tried making updates to my scss files and to make sure the theme is incorporated correctly.  I've spent an entire day searching for solutions and have found no answers.  I was under the impression that Ionic themes are default in an Ionic app and am not sure why this isn't working.

0" padding no-bounce text-center fullscreen expand="block">
DELETE STUDENT INFORMATION

button is rendered as white

Comment: Just to verify, you want to change the background color of the button?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

For button background try below.

```
<ion-button color="white">Button</ion-button>
```

If this doesn't work, please share your code. I will update your code.

Comment: BestMob, I've tried exactly that and it doesn't work.